# How to continuously deploy Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm forking the Gitlab CE source code to make a few small changes, and want to set up continuous deployment on my forked project to deploy to the cloud (could be an Ubuntu server in the cloud). Could you share some suggestions about how to set up this CD?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using GitLab GDK? https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-development-kit It's very simple to install and easy to contribute. It is very well documented [here](https://about.gitlab.com/contributing/)

Comment: Yes I am using gdk for my dev env, but I am looking for a solution to continuously deploy my modifications of gitlab to my web server.